# Printing plot inside of while loop in R

Tags: r, plot, while-loop

In R studio, I am having trouble printing every iteration of a while loop.

```
while(i < 10){
     print(plot(x, c(U[nx], U, U[1])))
     i = i + 1
     Sys.sleep(0.01)
     flush.console()
}
```

Nothing displays with or without the flush.console(), but it displays a plot when outside of the loop.

Comment: Have you initialized `i` before the loop? If yes, it works with me. `print(plot(1:10))` plotted the graphs.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?  To Rui's point, this code does work:
`i <- 1`
`while(i < 10){`
`print(plot(1:i))`
`i = i + 1`
`Sys.sleep(0.01)`
`flush.console()`
`}`

Comment: Hahaha I will double check on Monday!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just use a 'for' loop.  Something like this should work...

```
for(i in 1:10){
  print('hello')
  flush.console()
  i = i + 1
}
```